# Why does self is not defined and give me different results?

Tags: python, python-3.x

this code should do

- kilometer to meter convert
- meter to kilometer convert
- float should work
- should use classes and input
- doesn't matter you input km or m it will convert each other to each other
- sorry to my english

```py
class Convertor:    
    def __repr__(self, kilometer,meter):
        self.kilometer = metri/1000 
        self.meter = kilometri*1000

    def __str__(self):
        return self.kilometer, self.meter


program=input("please input number in KM or M: ")
if program=="KM" or "km":
    kilometri=input("please input only km: ")
if kilometri==int or float:
    print(self.kilometer)
else:
    print('please input only digits')
```

Comment: You can't use `self` outside a method.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/how-do-i-test-one-variable-against-multiple-values for how to write `if program == "KM" or "km"` properly.

Comment: can you fix it for me? how can i use it that make it work?

Comment: `if kilometri==int or float:` is not even close to the correct way to tell if the input is an integer or floatl

Comment: What is `metri`?

Comment: `self`  is just a regular local variable inside your methods, like any local variable, you can't use it outside your function.

Comment: Why are you assigning attributes inside the `__repr__` method? That looks more like the `__init__` method.

Comment: Both `__repr__` and `__str__` should return a string.

Comment: And, on top of that all, you didn't even mention what is wrong or post an error. I suggest you start working error by error because right now there are many issues with this code stated in the comments above. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response for how to take the user input correctly

Comment: the error is what they arleady said.`print(self.kilometer) NameError: name 'self' is not defined`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to call a self variable outside of Class, try like this:

```
variable = ClassName()
variable.kilometri
```